# Machine code JITs and the Execution Disable bit

Tags: machine-code, jit, llvm

How is runtime-generated machine-code (such as the output of a JIT), actually executed by the CPU if the CPU/OS has an Execution Disable bit?

As far as I know, many modern processors and Operating Systems include support for an NX bit, (including Intel and ARM), which prevents machine code that is stored at any address *other* than the code section of a compiled binary from being executed.  Clearly, this is a nice security advantage, because it prevents shell-code injection attacks.

But how do JIT engines, like LLVM, which dynamically generate machine-code, get around this?

Comment: Take a look at the implementations of Memory::allocateMappedMemory to see how it is done in LLVM. - [For *nix](https://github.com/llvm-mirror/llvm/blob/master/lib/Support/Unix/Memory.inc) - [For Windows](https://github.com/llvm-mirror/llvm/blob/master/lib/Support/Windows/Memory.inc)

Answer (score 6):

On Linux and many Posix systems, an application can change the protection of some range of the process [address space](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Address_space) in [virtual memory](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Virtual_memory) using the [mmap(2)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/mmap.2.html) and [mprotect(2)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/mprotect.2.html) syscalls.

So the JIT engine could use these (probably *before* emission of the machine code, but perhaps *after* it).

BTW, on *some* architectures, you may need to inform the CPU cache about newly available machine code segments, e.g. [`__builtin_clear_cache`](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Other-Builtins.html) of GCC.